# Dropdown focus is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I tried whenever alert is fired i want to set focus on that `control`. For that, I wrote something like below

```
 var checkIfUserRequesterApprover = document.getElementById('hdnSessionValue').value;

if (checkIfUserRequesterApprover == "VSAT Approver") {
    var ddlSiteApproved = $('#ddlSiteApproved').val();
    if (ddlSiteApproved == "Site Not Approved") {
        jAlert('Site cannot be Approved if marked as Site Not Approved in Site Approved/Not Approved', 'INFORMATION');
        return false;
        $("#ddlSiteApproved").focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do `focus` first and then `return false`. Just swap those lines.

Comment: @MilanChheda: tried with that, but the control is not highlighting. So i am unable to check whether the focus worked or not.

Comment: Once it reaches the return false,it ends the loop right.So,you need to put focus above the return statement.

Comment: And what is `jAlert`, if it's a custom alert that you click on, the focus will go there

Comment: @adeneo: `jAlert` is my custom alert which I show for validation purpose

Comment: Remove the `jAlert` and see if the focus is working properly or not.

Comment: @MilanChheda: yes, it takes their but can we light for more specification so that an end user who is non technical may get an idea.

Comment: So there is your problem and solution. For users, you can add red border or show some error message near the element.

Comment: @MilanChheda: yes, i will check for red border class and apply and check

Comment: You have call back function available for jAlert. You can write your focus code in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm not having an external link for jAlert, I cant post the fiddle here.
Also I'm not sure which version or file you are using for jAlert.

```
$(function(){
  jAlert('Site cannot be Approved if marked as Site Not Approved in Site Approved/Not Approved', 'INFORMATION', function(){
    $("#ddlSiteApproved").focus();
  });
});
```

Please check whether this will work for you.

In your case :

```
var checkIfUserRequesterApprover = document.getElementById('hdnSessionValue').value;

if (checkIfUserRequesterApprover == "VSAT Approver") {
  var ddlSiteApproved = $('#ddlSiteApproved').val();
  if (ddlSiteApproved == "Site Not Approved") {
    jAlert('Site cannot be Approved if marked as Site Not Approved in Site Approved/Not Approved', 'INFORMATION', function() {
      $("#ddlSiteApproved").focus();
    });
  }
}
```